# Why does my stackexchange post not produce all rows?

Tags: stack-exchange-data-explorer

Here is my code that I use over here - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1603630

```
SELECT title,concat('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',id), tags, score, 
creationDate From Posts
where (tags like '%<pymc3>%')
```

This tag has 697 questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pymc3) but I only get 693 rows.

Please let me know if any more information needs to be included. I have absolutely no background in writing queries and got the above code from a colleague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) FAQ:

> **How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
>
> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Jun 5 at 11:58.

You're seeing a view of the database as it was on 5 June 2022.

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with the code then :) ?

Comment: Well the formatting could use a little work, but functionally it is correct yes.